# USB Wifi not working on boot

Tags: pi-3b+

I am using TP-WN727N usb wifi module with raspberry pi 3b+. It using MT7601U driver. Wifi is working fine if I reconnect it but not detecting after reboot.

Comment: look for error messages in system logs

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple usb wifi module. Thanks to Jaromanda X, low voltage icon is not showing but when I check the system log it seems it needs more power at boot with additional usb devices so wifi module is not detected properly. So its works once reconnect. Power supply with more current solve my problem.